# Kafka with SSL - write to a topic - authorization error

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to produce from a command line to a topic that is on a local Kafka cluster with SSL enabled.

Topic was just created with:

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181  --create --topic simple    --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
```

Command for producing is:

```
kafka-avro-console-producer \ 
         --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic simple \
         --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}' \
         --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8080
```

Typing:

```
{"f1": "Alyssa"}
```

ERROR:

```
 {"f1": "Alyssa"}
Error when sending message to topic simple with key: null, value: 12 bytes with error: 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback:52) org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: 
Not authorized to access topics: [simple]
```

How to add access to this topic? 
What is the correct command for ACL (I am running it on my local machine).

Comment: Can you post the content of `server.properties` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an SSL protected cluster, then I suggest creating a config file, and using this parameter for the CLI to reference it.

```
--producer.config <String: config file>  Producer config properties file. Note
                                           that [producer-property] takes
                                           precedence over this config
```

An example file would look like

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
# SSL related properties
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/keystore-cert.jks
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore-cert.jks
ssl.key.password=xxxx
ssl.keystore.password=yyyy
ssl.truststore.password=zzzz
```

Otherise, you must pass each of these one-by-one onto the `--property` option

Answer (score 0):

I got the same  due to SSL properties, pls pass SSL.

below is sample for AVRO message

```
./kafka-avro-console-producer --topic <topic_name> --broker-list <broker:port> --producer.config ssl.properties --property schema.registry.url=<schema_registru_url (for avro msg)> --property value.schema="$(< /path/to/avro_chema.avsc)" --property key.schema='{"type":"string"}' --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=":"
```